# React Native Dnyamic amount of stack screens

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am making a React Native Quiz app (nothing special, same as all others).

However, there is one feature for it that I am unsure how to complete.

User Story: **The user should be able to go backwards during the quiz phase to view their previous answer.**

Is there any way to do this with Stack screens? I'm trying to figure this out how to do dynamic amount of stack screens, as some topics might have 3 questions or 9 questions. Currently, the only stack screen is the questions part, however I choose what question to view based on a bunch of functions (no matter what question, it is always the same screen).

Or is it suggested I make a custom function instead, that just moves backwards in what question to view? If I do this however, the user cannot swipe backwards to go to the previous question.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You dont have to create stack screen for every question.  In fact you can do that in single stack screen using condition and current index of question.

Comment: That is what I am currently doing. However, the user needs to be able to swipe backwards to view the previous question. isn't this only achievable with stack screen? @FerinPatel

Comment: If you create stack screen for every question, your app performance will decrease. In fact you can detect user gesture and swipe on screen and change the question accordingly on single stack screen

Comment: Ah perfect! So it is possible to setup a custom function that reacts to swipe? Because I already have a function that shows the previous question, can I just hook the swipe gesture to this function?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-swipe-gestures   this is easiest way to perform this

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and answer! I will check that out. Have a great week! @FerinPatel